# Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: Method Promise.prototype.then called on incompatible receiver

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, es6-promise, babel-polyfill

build with babel-preset-env, babel-polyfill library.

ERROR:
Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: Method Promise.prototype.then called on incompatible receiver function(t){this._c=[],this._a=void 0,this._s=0,this._d=!1,this._v=void 0,this._h=0,this._n=!1}

```
getEvents: async function() {
    const response = await fetch(
        '/api/v1/event/'
      {
        credentials: 'same-origin'
      }
    );

    // get Success
    this.events = await response.json();
    ...
}
```

package.json

```
"babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-remove-strict-mode": "0.0.2",
"babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
"grunt-babel": "^6.0.0",
```

if anyone knows what causing this, please answer.

I think might be a promise polyfill issue.. because 
`function(t){this._c=[],this._a=void 0,this._s=0,this._d=!1,this._v=void 0,this._h=0,this._n=!1}` this function came from promise polyfill..

stacktrace in babel-polyfil module.

```
var $resolve = function (value) {
  var promise = this;
  var then;
  if (promise._d) return;
  promise._d = true;
  promise = promise._w || promise; // unwrap
  try {
    if (promise === value) throw TypeError("Promise can't be resolved itself");
    if (then = isThenable(value)) {
      microtask(function () {
        var wrapper = { _w: promise, _d: false }; // wrap
        try {
```

**error happened in the next line**

```
          then.call(value, ctx($resolve, wrapper, 1), ctx($reject, wrapper, 1)); 
        } catch (e) {
          $reject.call(wrapper, e);
        }
      });
    } else {
      promise._v = value;
      promise._s = 1;
      notify(promise, false);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    $reject.call({ _w: promise, _d: false }, e); // wrap
  }
};
```

sorry I can't regenerate the error.. I remember it was triggered in that line.

Comment: Check that `fetch()` and `response.json()` are indeed returning `Promise` objects.

Comment: Please make sure to include the full stack trace when posting errors. For exceptions like this, usually the message on its own is only semi-useful. The polyfill you're showing isn't the one included by Babel, have you tried removing it?

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT Those were the Promises from polyfill

Comment: @loganfsmyth I added some more info. sorry for missing stacktrace..

Comment: @loganfsmyth umm.. when I using native promise with async/await generator, no error happens. Isn't es6-promise polyfill managed by Babel?

Comment: Babel's promise polyfill is `core-js`. `es6-promise` must be loaded by something else.